# Foreign name writing in Katakana

Tags: katakana, names

I was trying to figure out how the name "Saoirse" (pronounced as /Sur-sha/) would be written in Katakana characters. I was just a bit confused, although I know that Katakana bases on the literal pronounciation of a foreign word (ex: a name). Can someone help me with this one? I just got a little confused on how it'd be written in Katakana, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the following answers your question. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3

Comment: I listened to someone pronounce this name and don’t see how it should be written as シアーシァ. The “sur” part is pronounced the same as in “surface”. Then it would be better written as サーシャ. If you don’t like it to sound like Sasha, セアーシャ would sound closer than シアーシャ.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking the Japanese Wikipedia page of a famous person with the same name whenever you’re unsure about how to spell a foreign name. For example, Saoirse Ronan’s JP Wiki page spells her name as シアーシャ. Here’s the link: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3